# Is compensation possible for two day's delay following a flight cancellation?

Tags: air-travel, delays, easyjet

On New Year's Eve I was meant to be flying with easyJet from the north of the UK where I had been staying with my parents. A few hours before I planned to leave for the airport I read my flight was delayed ...then it was cancelled entirely. I had to rebook. The only alternative being two days later.

Is there any compensation due to me for this?

I know from the news that there was some problem with fog in London causing weather-based disruption there, however the weather was clear in the North. I think the problem there was due to the plane not being in place due to disturbances in the South. I strongly suspect from the low prices for flying on my original day that they made a conscious decision to cancel my flight to save another since a minimum of people would be disrupted.

Is there feasibly any compensation due to me for this delay?

It was a major annoyance which disrupted my plans for the last days of my holiday.

Exactly what are the rules for weather meaning airlines don't have to pay compensation, does it stretch down to knock-on effects?

Comment: The aircraft was probably out of position because of weather elsewhere.

Comment: Personally if it was domestic I would have blown the flight and tried to get a train back down south. Difficult on NYE, I know, but you would probably have got there in time for midnight if you had gone ASAP as you learned of the cancellation.

Answer (score 2):

Weather conditions are outside of the control of airlines so you had a good probability that they will deny to offer a compensation in this situation. They will claim that those were extraordinary circumstances that they couldn't have anticipated or avoided.

Having said that, they should have offered you some meals and pay for the extra accommodation.

The issue is that a lot of flights have been cancelled so you'll have difficulties to prove that the company made something wrong.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you are entitled to compensation according to European rules (as you were to fly from an EU-based airport) and you can find more about your rights and the complaint to submit here: http://europa.eu/youreurope/citizens/travel/passenger-rights/air/index_en.htm

Saying that, the airline will company justify through weather conditions, but depending on how they handled the cancellation, you might still be entitled compensation. You should try, we did and while the cause for us was technical problems, the airline still offered us a 50 % discount on a future flight. Good luck!